# Delphi Component Property Declaration

Tags: delphi, properties, components, declaration

Recently, I came across the following property declaration in the component `TDBNavigator`:

```
property Enabled;
[Default(False)]     <--------------------
property Flat: Boolean read FFlat write SetFlat default False;
```

What does the directive `[Default(False)]` mean? What is its main purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[Default(True|False)]` [Attribute](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.DefaultAttribute) does the same thing as the `default True|False` clause on the `property` itself.  DFM streaming supports both forms, and with each new IDE release, more and more properties are being moved to this Attribute model.  Why Embarcadero feels this is needed, I have no idea.  However, Attributes were added in XE3 and are accessible via Extended RTTI (the `System.Rtti` unit), and thus can be applied to things that old-style RTTI (the `System.TypInfo` unit) simply doesn't work for.  So, this may have been added to aid with other kinds of streaming frameworks, and they decided to apply it to DFMs, too.  Who knows.

Comment: Thank you, Remy. I appreciate your help. :)